# Fetch join on entity association with composite key generating multiple queries

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Edit - updated the question with the Equals and GetHasCode of my classes. I found out online that it was main source of errors in this case. But I guess I did implement these methods correctly. Please verify

### (wasn't able to add picture 'coz of reputation). Here is how the table structure looks like

```
company (id (pk), Name)

CompanyDivision (CompanyId (pk)(fk), DivisionNbr (pk), Description) - This refrences Company using CompanyId. CompanyId & DivisionNbr forms composite key

CompanyDivisionDepartment (CompanyId (pk)(fk), DivisionNbr (pk)(fk), DepartmentNumber (pk), Description)
  This table references CompanyDivision using CompanyId & DivisionNbr. CompanyId & DivisionNbr & DepartmentNumber forms composite key
```

HQL i used to get departments

```
 var q = @"from Department dept join fetch dept.Division where dept.DepartmentNumber=:id";
    IList<Department> depts = session.CreateQuery(q).SetInt32("id", 1).List<Department>();
```

These are the queries than ran, found them using Nhibernate profiler, after running that HQL. Tried all ways I came across online with no luck. Please help in understanding why the last 2 queries have run even when I am fetching the association by join

```
select department0_.CompanyId     as CompanyId1_0_,
department0_.DivisionNbr   as Division2_1_0_,
department0_.DepartmentNbr as Departme3_1_0_,
division1_.CompanyId       as CompanyId2_1_,
division1_.DivisionNbr     as Division2_2_1_,
department0_.Description   as Descript4_1_0_,
division1_.Description     as Descript3_2_1_
from   CompanyDivisionDepartment department0_
inner join CompanyDivision division1_
on department0_.CompanyId = division1_.CompanyId
and department0_.DivisionNbr = division1_.DivisionNbr
where  department0_.DepartmentNbr = 1 /* @p0 */

SELECT division0_.CompanyId   as CompanyId2_0_,
division0_.DivisionNbr as Division2_2_0_,
division0_.Description as Descript3_2_0_
FROM   CompanyDivision division0_
WHERE  division0_.CompanyId = 1 /* @p0 */
and division0_.DivisionNbr = 1 /* @p1 */

SELECT division0_.CompanyId   as CompanyId2_0_,
division0_.DivisionNbr as Division2_2_0_,
division0_.Description as Descript3_2_0_
FROM   CompanyDivision division0_
WHERE  division0_.CompanyId = 2 /* @p0 */
and division0_.DivisionNbr = 1 /* @p1 */
```

mappings

company

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NH" namespace="NH">
  <class name="Company">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="assigned"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Name"></property>
    <set name="Divisions" table="CompanyDivision">
      <key column="CompanyId"></key>
      <one-to-many class="Division"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Division

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NH" namespace="NH">
  <class name="Division" table="CompanyDivision">
    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one name="Company" class="Company" column="CompanyId"></key-many-to-one>
      <key-property name="DivisionNumber" column="DivisionNbr"></key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="Description" column="Description"></property>
    <set name="Departments" table="CompanyDivisionDepartment">
      <key>
        <column name="CompanyId"></column>
        <column name="DivisionNbr"></column>
      </key>
      <one-to-many class="Department"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Department

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NH" namespace="NH">
  <class name="Department" table="CompanyDivisionDepartment">
    <composite-id>
      <key-many-to-one name="Division" class="Division">
        <column name="CompanyId"></column>
        <column name="DivisionNbr"></column>
      </key-many-to-one>
      <key-property name="DepartmentNumber" column="DepartmentNbr"></key-property>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="Description"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Equals and GetHashCode mappings

```
public class Division
    {
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public virtual int DivisionNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
            Division that = obj as Division;
            if (that == null) return false;
            if (this.Company.Id != that.Company.Id) return false;
            if(this.DivisionNumber != this.DivisionNumber) return false;
            return true;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hash = 13;
            hash = (hash * 7) + this.Company.Id.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 7) + this.DivisionNumber.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }



public class Department
    {
        public virtual Division Division { get; set; }
        public virtual int DepartmentNumber { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;

            Department that = obj as Department;
            if (that == null) return false;
            if (this.Division.Company.Id != that.Division.Company.Id) return false;
            if (this.Division.DivisionNumber != that.Division.DivisionNumber) return false;
            if (this.DepartmentNumber != that.DepartmentNumber) return false;

            return true;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hash = 13;
            hash = (hash * 7) + this.DepartmentNumber.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 7) + this.Division.Company.Id.GetHashCode();
            hash = (hash * 7) + this.Division.DivisionNumber.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As a random Try change this:

```
<composite-id>
  <key-many-to-one name="Division" class="Division">
    <column name="CompanyId"></column>
    <column name="DivisionNbr"></column>
  </key-many-to-one>
  <key-property name="DepartmentNumber" column="DepartmentNbr"></key-property>
</composite-id>
```

To this:

```
<composite-id>
  <key-many-to-one name="Division" class="Division">
    <column name="CompanyId"></column>
    <column name="DivisionNbr"></column>
  </key-many-to-one>
</composite-id>
<key-property name="DepartmentNumber" column="DepartmentNbr"></key-property>
```

Or this:

```
<composite-id>
  <key-many-to-one name="Division" class="Division">
    <column name="CompanyId"></column>
    <column name="DivisionNbr"></column>
    <column name="DepartmentNumber" column="DepartmentNbr"></column>
  </key-many-to-one>
</composite-id>
```

Comment: thank you for taking time and looking into it. the mapping changes didn't work for me